# Is it possible to find the path of a running program?

Tags: process

I have a `xmms2d` process running, but two possible executable files (in different directories, both in the executable path) that could have spawned it. I suspect that one of those is corrupted, because sometimes this program works and sometimes it doesn't. The process running now works, so I want to delete (or rename) the other one.

`ps ax|grep "xmms"` returns `8505 ?        SLl    2:38 xmms2d -v` without path information. Given the PID, could I find whether it was run from `/usr/bin/xmms2d` or `/usr/local/bin/xmms2d`?

Thanks!

Comment: `ps -C xmms` should make your grep obsolete.

Comment: pgrep would do it too.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
ls -l /proc/8505/exe
```

Or if you don't want to parse the output of `ls`, just do:

```
readlink /proc/8505/exe
```

or

```
realpath /proc/8505/exe
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are running Solaris, the way is slightly different from the Linux one suggested:

```
$ for i in $(pgrep bash)
do
  printf "%6d %s\n" $i $(readlink /proc/$i/path/a.out)
done
   577 /usr/bin/bash
 11247 /usr/bin/bash
 13921 /usr/bin/bash
 13992 /tmp/bash
```

Should you want to know the current working directory of running processes, you can use:

```
pwdx $(pgrep xmms)
```

eg:

```
$ pwdx $(pgrep ksh)
2904: /home/jlliagre
2906: /home/jlliagre
3844: /tmp
```

Comment: (deleted my comment as it no longer applied after your edit:)

Answer (score -1):

I start mousepad from the shell:

```
mousepad & 
[1] 24289
```

check, where it comes from:

```
which mousepad 
   /usr/bin/mousepad
```

start it with path:

```
/usr/bin/mousepad &
```

look via ps:

```
ps v -C mousepad 
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME  MAJFL   TRS   DRS   RSS %MEM COMMAND
24289 pts/3    S      0:00      3    62 85441 10964  1.0 mousepad
24292 pts/3    S      0:00      0    62 85433 10864  1.0 /usr/bin/mousepad
```

As we see, the one invoked without path is displayed without path, and started with the PATH, and therefore to be found by

```
which mousepad
```

Simple as that, isn't it? 
Wait!
What if I start mousepad from the menu? Well, it might be specified with or without using the PATH settings. I tried. 
A normal start leads to a simple 'mousepad' in `ps v -C`. Since ~/bin is the first part of my PATH I create a dummy there, and, voila, the dummy is started from the menu.

But what if you start a program which deletes itself? Which will not find the deleted program and report a wrong one, if there is a second in the path.

So that's a race condition. If you know that your programs don't delete themselves or aren't moved while you're investigating their location, `ps v -C NAME` and `which NAME` should work pretty well.

Comment: Will this always work? Suppose I have an executable in two different directories and I run `./someexecutable` in both?

Comment: No, of course not, because both will show up as ./someexecutable or /bin/bash ./someexecutable

Answer (score -4):

Go ahead and delete both the files (without force -f option). The file that gets deleted is the one, that was not running !!

System executable file locking will not allow you to delete any file that is currently under execution.

Comment: Your answer doesn't provide an real answer to the question.

Comment: It is also wrong. You can delete running executables without issue. How do you think packages such as `init`, which are always running, get upgraded? You cannot *modify* a running executable.

Comment: This is alarmingly wrong -- don't do this